# Keep getting Type Error running awk in Python

Tags: python, awk

I get the following error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.Pathlike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

I am open to not using a subprocess to run the awk and to use something other than awk

```
subprocess.run(['awk', '-F', ',', '!seen[$1]++', filename], stdout=open(ndfile, 'w'))
```

Comment: I think `ndfile` is already an open file, not a filename. So just use `stdout=ndfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can trivially replace the Awk script with native Python code.

```
with open(filename, "r") as lines, open(ndfile, 'w') as output:
    seen = set()
    for line in lines:
        first = line.rstrip('\r\n').split(',')[0]
        if first not in seen:
            output.write(line)
```

The immediate cause of your error is that Python recieves `bytes` from `subprocess` unless you specify `text=True` (or explicitly `.decode` the bytes you receive) but the output filehandle was not opened in binary mode (`"wb"`). But really, don't run Awk from Python.